# iOS App - license per device

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, mobile-application, license-key

we have mobile application for Android and iOS. The app has two versions Free and Full. For using Full version you have to buy a license. The license is linked with device and you can use the license at only one device. The Full app purchase you can make in our e-shop, in the app and in one more other app. We manage licenses ourselves and everything was fine today.

We released new iOS version today and the version was rejected because of possibility of purchasing app with other than the in-app purchase API. We can't use in-app purchase API, because the purchased app is linked with apple ID, so the user can use app at every device, but we need to link the app with only one device.

Is there any possibility how to make it? Thanks.

Comment: What you want to do seems to be going very much "against the grain" as far as what Apple appears to be doing cutting off access to unique device features such as MAC addresses. As for implementing something like that, two things come to mind: __UIDevice.identifierForVendor__ and __ASIdentifierManager.advertisingIdentifier__. Alternatively, instead of identifying a particular device, you may consider generating a unique token and storing it on a device in a place that would not be backed up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already mechanism to identify devices, but he is still problem with purchasing. For example, user with Apple ID "XXX" buy a license via in-app purchase API on his iPhone, then download app on his iPad. According to Apple has also full version on iPad (because of same Apple ID) and can't buy another license. But our business model is 1 license = 1 device. I'm able to detect the situation and tell the user: "If you can license on this device (iPad), contact our support and buy it directly, not via in-app purchase API". Do you think is it possible approach?

Comment: There are 2 types of in-app purchases: consumable and non-consulable. From the point of view of your situation, this looks like a consumable in-app purchase. You say that you already can distinguish between devices; in that case, upon in-app purchase delivery you can generate a license code bound to that particular device. There is also a log of purchases stored in app's "receipt" and each purchase is associated with a unique transaction ID, which you can store on the server and use to restore the license in the future if necessary.

Comment: Aside from device identification and app store user ID considerations, are you even allowed to do this? Can you install a free app and use a mechanism other then the app store to purchase a license and unlock functionality (like a Netflix model).

Answer (score 3):

iOS App store apps are strictly prohibited from locking to (or even detecting or using in any way) any unique iOS device ID.  You will need to license your app differently, or not use Apple's App store for app distribution.